# Proper way to read 'int * ptr=&x'

Tags: c, pointers, initialization, declaration

The following code is easily interpreted as

```
int x=4;
int *ptr;  // ptr is a pointer to an int
ptr=&x; // the address of x  is assigned to the pointer ptr
```

But the following equivalent code, may read misleadingly like

```
int *ptr=&x; //  the address of x is assigned to  *ptr, which is an integer
```

that is it seems to be interpreted as assigning the address of x to the pointed value *ptr `(int *ptr )= &x`
The correct interpretation as the one when declaration and initialization are separated should be  written something like `int *(ptr = &x)`,to make evident that the assignment is to the pointer and not to the pointed location but this gives an error, why is that? And what is the best way to read and think of `int *ptr=&x`?

Comment: It's pretty simple, the type is `int *`, no matter the distance from `int` and `*`. You could even write `int                        *                ptr=x;` and that'd still be valid. Reading it correctly is merely a matter of habit.

Comment: @Marco Bonelli  I see, but I usually find it written as int     *ptr  , thati is the * next to the pointer name ,which doesn't help. I t could be interpreted as int  (*ptr) and it is correct to say that the value pointed by ptr is an integer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`int *` is the type, so it makes perfect sense. It's just that pointer notation in C can take some effort to get used to. But look at this code

```
typedef int* int_ptr;
int x;
int_ptr ptr = &x;
```

Same thing. However, it's often advised to NOT typedef pointers.

The confusion comes from that `*` serves two roles. It is BOTH to name a type AND to dereference a pointer. An example of the first is `sizeof(int*)`

If you declare several pointers at once it looks messier, but it's still the same. In general, it's recommended to not declare more than one pointer at once. Because if we would like to do the above thing with two pointers, it would look like this:

```
int *pa = &x, *pb = &x;
```

That's the same as

```
int *pa = &x;
int *pb = &x;
```

And this does something completely different and will generate a warning because you're assigning the address of a variable to the `pb` variable that has type `int`

```
int *pa = &x, pb = &x;
```

However, using the typedef from above, you can (but probably shouldn't) do this:

```
int_ptr pa=&x, pb = &x;
```

But one way to think of it is that it makes no sense at all in any situation to dereference an uninitialized pointer.

> And what is the best way to read and think of `int *ptr=&x`?

Take the fact that it does not make sense to dereference an uninitialized pointer. And you're doing an initialization of a pointer, and therefore you should initialize it with a (valid) address.

> Ok, I see that, another thing. If the type is `int*` why is it almost always written like with the `*` next to the pointer variable instead, like `int *ptr`?, it would make more sense, even if it is the same to write it like `int* ptr`.

Because, then it would be MUCH easier to forget the asterisk if you declare several pointers at once. That would give the impression that    `int* p,q;` declares two pointers.

C pointer syntax is clunky. It's a very old language. Just get used to it. It will never change. Just for fun, here is a page that can tell what a declaration is https://cdecl.org/ so try these:

```
int (*p)[3]
int *p[3]
const int *p[3]
int *const p[3]
const int (*p)[3]
int (*const p)[3]
```

Comment: Gets trickier for lines like: `int *px = &x, *py = &y;`.

Comment: Oh I used to think of int *ptr as int (*ptr), ie dereferencing the pointer in the declaration, since it makes sense to say that the content of the address ptr , which is *ptr is an int. Is this way of seeing it wrong?

Comment: @AdrianMole True. Fixed it.

Comment: @J.C.VegaO Hmmm, how should I describe it? What you're saying makes sense, but it's wrong. And look at my last paragraph. It NEVER makes sense to dereference an uninitialized pointer.

Comment: Ok, I see that, another thing .If the type is int*  why is it almost always written like with the`*` next to the pointer variable instead, like `int  *ptr` ?, it would make more sense, even if it is the same to write it like  `int* ptr`

Comment: @J.C.VegaO Updated answer

Comment: @J.C.VegaO Because for example `int a, *b, c;` defines two integers and a pointer.

Answer (score 4):

This is, admittedly a weird part of C and it's mostly due to C's evolution.

In C's syntax, declarations aim to mirror use, so that after `int *x;`, `*x` resolves to an `int` and `*x=42` assigns to that `int`. But initializations, which are started with `=` after the `specifiers declarator` part of a declaration, are syntactically and semantically different from an assignments.

(Initialization can "assign" to static/filescope variables and such an assignment generates no code: it simply contributes to the makeup of the resulting binary. Assignments always generate code unless optimizations can delete it)

Initializations and assignments used to be very differently looking in prehistoric C, where you'd initialize without the `=` sign as in `int x 42;`. (Even after the `=` was added to the syntax of initializations, it was long impossible to initialize local, nonstatic, variables which meant situations such as `int *p = &x;` didn't arise all that often.)

The old syntax had problems (would `int x (42);` also declare and initialize `x` or would it be a function declaration?) and that's why it was replaced, but I like how it emphasized that initializations are different from assignments.

Unfortunately with the new syntax (as in `int x, *p = &x;`) this distinction is not all that apparent, and you simply have to remember that when you have type specifiers (`int`) at the left end, then the `=` does not denote  an assignment where you  can just look at `*p = &x` but rather that it's an **initialization** where you have to look at the whole declaration and see what's declared (`x` as an `int` and `p` as a pointer to `int`) . The `=` in that context then initializes the declared identifier.

Comment: Thanks this pretty much helps to know why some assignment-looking expressions are not assignments. I don't know if I should be using the word expression, statement of something else here, though, another weird technicality

Answer (score 2):

You could write

```
int ( *ptr ) = &x;
```

or even like

```
int ( * ( ptr ) ) = &x;
```

Though this record

```
int *ptr = &x;
```

is clear for each C programmer because it is a declaration and not an assignment statement. Moreover in C opposite to C++ declarations are not statements.

That is 1) you may not enclose a declaration in parentheses as you wrote `(int *ptr )= &x` and 2) you may enclose a declarator in parentheses.

If to follow your logic then you should write the declaration like

```
int *p = ( p = &x );
```

that makes the declaration more confusing.:)

Here is a demonstrative program that shows some examples of declarations and initializations of a pointer.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    int x = 10;
    
    int *p1 = &x;
    int ( *p2 ) = &x;
    int ( *( p3 ) ) = &x;
    
    int typedef *T;
    
    T ( p4 ) = &x;
    
    printf( "*p1 = %d\n", *p1 );
    printf( "*p2 = %d\n", *p2 );
    printf( "*p3 = %d\n", *p3 );
    printf( "*p4 = %d\n", *p4 );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
*p1 = 10
*p2 = 10
*p3 = 10
*p4 = 10
```

Pay attention to that in C as in many other languages some symbols are overloaded and their meanings depend on the context. For example the symbol `&` can denote the address of operator and the bitwise AND operator and by the way in C++ this symbol also can denote a reference.

Comment: "int *ptr = &x is clear for each C programmer because it is a declaration and not an assignment statement."   Isn't this a declaration plus an assigment in a single line? I mean it is a declaration plus an initialization and a initialization is an assigment of a value

Comment: @J.C.VegaO There is one line containing a declaration. Initialization is not the assignment statement.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get why initialization is not an assigment, When I do `int x; x=4;` the second statement initializes the variable using the assigment operator `=`

Comment: @J.C.VegaO Initialization is basically assignment done during declaration. But there are some special cases. In some cases you must use initialization and in some cases you cannot do that.

Comment: @J.C.VegaO If to consider initialization as a strict term defined in the C Standard then initialization is not an assignment. And we are speaking now in the context of the C Standard. In a more general context the term initialization is used to denote any assignment of a value to a variable.

Comment: @klutt so initialization is when you do assigment and declaration in a single line like when declaring a const variable, where you cannot leave the assigment for the following line

Comment: What Vlad is saying is true. Technically, an initialization is NOT an assignment, but it can be viewed as assignment during declaration, even though it's not 100% true. And also, it's common to use the term initialization for the FIRST assignment.

Comment: @J.C.VegaO In C there are defined declarations, statements and expressions. A declaration is not a statement and is not an expression. When the term assignment is used then it is assumed that you are speaking either about the assignment statement or about the assignment expression.

Comment: @J.C.VegaO You can look here https://www.lysator.liu.se/c/ANSI-C-grammar-y.html and here http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2310.pdf if you want to dig deep

Comment: `int typedef *T;` ??? Ok, that's something I hadn't seen before.

Answer (score 1):

Compare the following.

```
int n = 5;     // (a) defines 'int' variable 'n' and initializes it to '5'

int *p;        // (b) defines 'int*' pointer variable 'p`
p = &n;        //     initializes 'p' to '&n'

int *p1 = p;   // (c) defines 'int*' pointer variable 'p1' and initializes it to 'p' 
               //     syntactically, it looks just like (a), but for a pointer type

int *p2 = &n;  // (d) same as (b) and (c) combined into a one-liner

int n3 = 7, *p3 = &n3;  // (e) same as (a), (b) and (c) combined into a one-liner
```

Answer (score 0):

when declare a pointer, int *p is equal to int* p;  int* is a type.